# Compute column based on the value of another column with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my `SELECT` statement, the value of `CusLifeTime` is calculated like this.

```
CASE 
   WHEN ISNULL(c.cus_DateStop, '') = '' THEN DATEDIFF(yy,cus_DateStart , GETDATE())
   WHEN DATEDIFF(yy,cus_DateStart , cus_DateStop) < 0 THEN -1
   ELSE DATEDIFF(yy,cus_DateStart , cus_DateStop)
END AS CusLifeTime,
```

Now I'd like use the value of `CusLifeTime` in another column (again using `CASE`) in the same `SELECT` statement.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you wont be able to use it in the same select but you can wrap the `select` in a CTE or a derived table and then use `CusLifeTime` in another column

Comment: One alternative is to use subquery.

Comment: you could make a store function and just provide the required parameters

Answer (score 0):

The two "normal" ways are using a CTE or subquery.  SQL Server also lets you use `apply`, which can be convenient because it limits the query depth:

```
SELECT . . .,
       v.CusLifeTime
FROM . . . OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN c.cus_DateStop IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(year, cus_DateStart, GETDATE())
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, cus_DateStart, cus_DateStop) < 0 THEN -1
                   ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, cus_DateStart, cus_DateStop)
              END)
     ) AS v(CusLifeTime)
```

The column can then be used in expressions.

Notes:

- I recommend that you use full date part names for functions that take them.  This is clearer for people reading the code and removes ambiguity about whether "mm" means months or minutes.
- Do you really know what `DATEDIFF()` does?  You might be surprised.  Read the documentation.  It returns the number of date part boundaries between two values.
- Just explicitly say `IS NULL` rather than the strange construct using `ISNULL()`.  The former is clearer and standard and allows the use of indexes.

Comment: Re `IS NULL`, does it apply to empty strings as well?

Comment: Re `DATEDIFF()` what do you recommend to calculate the difference between two dates?

Comment: @Disasterkid . . . `IS NULL` does not apply to empty strings, but based on the usage of the column, it appears to be a date/datetime.  Such a column cannot be "empty" without being `NULL`.  As for `DATEDIFF()`, you should just be sure it is doing what you really want.

Comment: The column is actually an `NVARCHAR` and that's why I used that weird convert. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: @Disasterkid . . . A column called `DateStop` should not be stored as a string.  SQL has native data types for a reason.  You should fix the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below:

```
SELECT CusLifeTime,  
CASE WHEN CusLifeTime = 0 THEN 
    'SomeValue' 
ELSE 'AnotherValue' END AS ComputedCusLifeTime
FROM (
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(c.cus_DateStop, '') = '' THEN DATEDIFF(yy,cus_DateStart , GETDATE())
       WHEN DATEDIFF(yy,cus_DateStart , cus_DateStop) < 0 THEN -1
       ELSE DATEDIFF(yy,cus_DateStart , cus_DateStop)
    END AS CusLifeTime
FROM myTable) t
```